# Change Parent Class onfocus

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a field where I want selection of one of the input boxes to change the background color of the field. My attempt was to change the html class of the parent of the input, which is the field, through a simple `onfocus` action, but I'm seeing no reaction.

I have the following, and have double checked the class names.

In the script:

```
function changefield()
{
document.getElementById(this.parentNode).className = "temp_field";
}
```

In the html:

```
<input class="type1" type="text" size="30" onFocus="changefield()">
```

This feels like I'm making some fairly obvious beginners' mistake, but I've already had two people play with it to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- Inside `changefield`, `this` refers to `window`, which does not not have a `parentNode` property, so you are passing `undefined` to `getElementById`.
- Even if it had a parent node, `this.parentNode` would return a DOM node, while `getElementById` expects a string.

A quick solution would be to just pass the DOM element you want to modify to your function:

```
function changefield(element) {
    element.className = "temp_field";
}
```

and

```
onFocus="changefield(this.parentNode)"
```

Even if the parent node has an ID, it does not make sense to search for the node if you already have a reference to id (`.parentNode`).

For more information about event handling and how to bind event handlers, have a look at [the excellent articles at quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `this.parentNode` to `getElementById()`.

`getElementId()` expects an id string as an argument (not a DOM element).